# How to run a script for more than 10 minutes in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, queue, task, task-queue

I know that Task Queues can only run for 10 minutes, and I have a script that cannot finish in that time limit. Is there a way to exceed this time constraint? I looked into backends, as I know those have no limits, but I couldn't find the documentation on how to make one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a backend. They're documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/).

If your script won't finish in time because it's processing too much data, though, you probably want to consider rewriting it if you want it to scale. Breaking it up into chunks and running them on the task queue is a common approach, and means your task won't run slower and slower as your dataset increases in size.